# Swift (iOS 8) - User is not being prompted for permission to use location

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have already added the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` Key in `Info.plist`

I have also requested authorization, however, the app does not prompt for permission, and the Location Settings in Privacy Settings does not have an option for While Using under the app name. I have a feeling that the `Info.plist` file is not updating in the app itself when it is built, however I am unable to pinpoint the true cause of the problem. Any advice? All help is appreciated.

The `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` Key has been added to `Info.plist` and the build has been cleaned and the project has been rebuilt, but still no success.

Comment: Set the always plist key and clean the build to start

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use when using location manager.

```
func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()


if ( ios8() ) {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
 }
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

  /*
iOS 8 Utility
*/
func ios8() -> Bool {
    if ( NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 ) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

I also have the following in my plist.

```
Privacy - Location Usage Description
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

Comment: your code is wrong. The `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` and `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` only available on ios 8. If you want to support ios7, use `startUpdatingLocation()`

Comment: I have the same keys in my plist, but I think for some reason that the plist doesn't update when the app builds. Is there a setting which could be preventing this? I remember doing the same thing in Objective-C, and I didn't have any issues.

Comment: In your target and build settings what dose the section on packaging look like?

Comment: everything is just as it came
i didnt change anything
is there anything i should look out for?

Comment: You started the project from scratch and have not moved the info.plist? Did you delete the app from either the device or the simulator and then try running it again?

Comment: Yes I have tried deleting the app and running it again. No luck.

Comment: You have it set to string for it's type and you have a value?

Comment: Yes, all the keys have values.

Comment: Post your code that you use to call the location update.